# Apply two different fills in the same graph (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically, I have this grid.

[image]

With the code below, I realise this graph :

[image]

```
Source = ifelse(DF$Groupr == "0", "NULL", "OK") 
cols <- c("0" = "White", "1" = "#00AFBB", "2" = "#E7B800", 
          "3" = "Springgreen4", "4" = "purple3")
DF <- cbind(DF,Source)
my_breaks = c(1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 687)
my_breakslab = c("1 (0)", "4 (2)", "16 (4)", "64 (6)", "256 (8)", "687(Maximum)")

#Graph
ggShape <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = DF, 
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, color = Groupr, 
                   alpha = Source, fill = PORT))  + 
  scale_color_manual(values = alpha(cols, c(0,1,1,1,1)), name="Groups", 
                     breaks=c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"), 
                     labels=c("No value", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4")) +
  scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(1, 687), low = "red", high = "black", trans = 'log2', 
                        breaks = my_breaks, labels = my_breakslab, space = "Lab", 
                        name="Density of Boat\nPer area (log2)", na.value = NA) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0,0.80), guide = "none") +
  geom_path(color = "black") +
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude", title="Distribution of ship density per area", 
       subtitle="by islands (landing)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey90", size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                         colour ="black"), 
        aspect.ratio = 1)
print(ggShape)
```

I want to have a better visibility between the different groups, by adding a second fill. This second fill would have the same values as the `color` aesthetic (i.e. : `DF$Groupr`), exclusively  for the polygons with an 'NA' value. For polygons with other values, I will keep the basic fill(i.e.: `DF$PORT`, in `scale_fill_continuous`'s red to black).

I also thought about add the same data.frame under this one. The data.frame under would be filled with the same colors as the boundaries (i.e.: `DF$Groupr`), with a high transparency. And the one upside, would keep the same fill as the basic graph.

In these two cases, I couldn't put a second `scale_fill` in the graph.

This is a part of the data.frame :

```
head(Gr21, n = 200)
         long      lat order  hole piece  id group Id ET_ID ET_Index Groupr PORT Source
1   -33.83333 40.33333     1 FALSE     1  A1  A1.1  0  1748    26--6      0   NA   NULL
2   -34.00000 40.33333     2 FALSE     1  A1  A1.1  0  1748    26--6      0   NA   NULL
3   -34.00000 40.50000     3 FALSE     1  A1  A1.1  0  1748    26--6      0   NA   NULL
4   -33.83333 40.50000     4 FALSE     1  A1  A1.1  0  1748    26--6      0   NA   NULL
5   -33.83333 40.33333     5 FALSE     1  A1  A1.1  0  1748    26--6      0   NA   NULL
6   -32.33333 40.33333     6 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15      4    1     OK
7   -32.50000 40.33333     7 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15      4    1     OK
8   -32.50000 40.50000     8 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15      4    1     OK
9   -32.33333 40.50000     9 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15      4    1     OK
10  -32.33333 40.33333    10 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15      4    1     OK
11  -32.16667 40.33333    11 FALSE     1 A11 A11.1  0  1758   26--16      0   NA   NULL
12  -32.33333 40.33333    12 FALSE     1 A11 A11.1  0  1758   26--16      0   NA   NULL
13  -32.33333 40.50000    13 FALSE     1 A11 A11.1  0  1758   26--16      0   NA   NULL
14  -32.16667 40.50000    14 FALSE     1 A11 A11.1  0  1758   26--16      0   NA   NULL
15  -32.16667 40.33333    15 FALSE     1 A11 A11.1  0  1758   26--16      0   NA   NULL
16  -32.00000 40.33333    16 FALSE     1 A12 A12.1  0  1759   26--17      0   NA   NULL
17  -32.16667 40.33333    17 FALSE     1 A12 A12.1  0  1759   26--17      0   NA   NULL
18  -32.16667 40.50000    18 FALSE     1 A12 A12.1  0  1759   26--17      0   NA   NULL
19  -32.00000 40.50000    19 FALSE     1 A12 A12.1  0  1759   26--17      0   NA   NULL
20  -32.00000 40.33333    20 FALSE     1 A12 A12.1  0  1759   26--17      0   NA   NULL
21  -31.83333 40.33333    21 FALSE     1 A13 A13.1  0  1760   26--18      4    1     OK
22  -32.00000 40.33333    22 FALSE     1 A13 A13.1  0  1760   26--18      4    1     OK
23  -32.00000 40.50000    23 FALSE     1 A13 A13.1  0  1760   26--18      4    1     OK
24  -31.83333 40.50000    24 FALSE     1 A13 A13.1  0  1760   26--18      4    1     OK
25  -31.83333 40.33333    25 FALSE     1 A13 A13.1  0  1760   26--18      4    1     OK
26  -31.66667 40.33333    26 FALSE     1 A14 A14.1  0  1761   26--19      0   NA   NULL
27  -31.83333 40.33333    27 FALSE     1 A14 A14.1  0  1761   26--19      0   NA   NULL
28  -31.83333 40.50000    28 FALSE     1 A14 A14.1  0  1761   26--19      0   NA   NULL
29  -31.66667 40.50000    29 FALSE     1 A14 A14.1  0  1761   26--19      0   NA   NULL
30  -31.66667 40.33333    30 FALSE     1 A14 A14.1  0  1761   26--19      0   NA   NULL
31  -31.50000 40.33333    31 FALSE     1 A15 A15.1  0  1762   26--20      0   NA   NULL
32  -31.66667 40.33333    32 FALSE     1 A15 A15.1  0  1762   26--20      0   NA   NULL
33  -31.66667 40.50000    33 FALSE     1 A15 A15.1  0  1762   26--20      0   NA   NULL
34  -31.50000 40.50000    34 FALSE     1 A15 A15.1  0  1762   26--20      0   NA   NULL
35  -31.50000 40.33333    35 FALSE     1 A15 A15.1  0  1762   26--20      0   NA   NULL
36  -31.33333 40.33333    36 FALSE     1 A16 A16.1  0  1763   26--21      4    1     OK
37  -31.50000 40.33333    37 FALSE     1 A16 A16.1  0  1763   26--21      4    1     OK
38  -31.50000 40.50000    38 FALSE     1 A16 A16.1  0  1763   26--21      4    1     OK
39  -31.33333 40.50000    39 FALSE     1 A16 A16.1  0  1763   26--21      4    1     OK
40  -31.33333 40.33333    40 FALSE     1 A16 A16.1  0  1763   26--21      4    1     OK
41  -31.16667 40.33333    41 FALSE     1 A17 A17.1  0  1764   26--22      0   NA   NULL
42  -31.33333 40.33333    42 FALSE     1 A17 A17.1  0  1764   26--22      0   NA   NULL
43  -31.33333 40.50000    43 FALSE     1 A17 A17.1  0  1764   26--22      0   NA   NULL
44  -31.16667 40.50000    44 FALSE     1 A17 A17.1  0  1764   26--22      0   NA   NULL
45  -31.16667 40.33333    45 FALSE     1 A17 A17.1  0  1764   26--22      0   NA   NULL
46  -31.00000 40.33333    46 FALSE     1 A18 A18.1  0  1765   26--23      0   NA   NULL
47  -31.16667 40.33333    47 FALSE     1 A18 A18.1  0  1765   26--23      0   NA   NULL
48  -31.16667 40.50000    48 FALSE     1 A18 A18.1  0  1765   26--23      0   NA   NULL
49  -31.00000 40.50000    49 FALSE     1 A18 A18.1  0  1765   26--23      0   NA   NULL
50  -31.00000 40.33333    50 FALSE     1 A18 A18.1  0  1765   26--23      0   NA   NULL
51  -30.83333 40.33333    51 FALSE     1 A19 A19.1  0  1766   26--24      0   NA   NULL
52  -31.00000 40.33333    52 FALSE     1 A19 A19.1  0  1766   26--24      0   NA   NULL
53  -31.00000 40.50000    53 FALSE     1 A19 A19.1  0  1766   26--24      0   NA   NULL
54  -30.83333 40.50000    54 FALSE     1 A19 A19.1  0  1766   26--24      0   NA   NULL
55  -30.83333 40.33333    55 FALSE     1 A19 A19.1  0  1766   26--24      0   NA   NULL
56  -33.66667 40.33333    56 FALSE     1  A2  A2.1  0  1749    26--7      4    1     OK
57  -33.83333 40.33333    57 FALSE     1  A2  A2.1  0  1749    26--7      4    1     OK
58  -33.83333 40.50000    58 FALSE     1  A2  A2.1  0  1749    26--7      4    1     OK
59  -33.66667 40.50000    59 FALSE     1  A2  A2.1  0  1749    26--7      4    1     OK
60  -33.66667 40.33333    60 FALSE     1  A2  A2.1  0  1749    26--7      4    1     OK
61  -30.66667 40.33333    61 FALSE     1 A20 A20.1  0  1767   26--25      0   NA   NULL
62  -30.83333 40.33333    62 FALSE     1 A20 A20.1  0  1767   26--25      0   NA   NULL
63  -30.83333 40.50000    63 FALSE     1 A20 A20.1  0  1767   26--25      0   NA   NULL
64  -30.66667 40.50000    64 FALSE     1 A20 A20.1  0  1767   26--25      0   NA   NULL
65  -30.66667 40.33333    65 FALSE     1 A20 A20.1  0  1767   26--25      0   NA   NULL
66  -30.50000 40.33333    66 FALSE     1 A21 A21.1  0  1768   26--26      0   NA   NULL
67  -30.66667 40.33333    67 FALSE     1 A21 A21.1  0  1768   26--26      0   NA   NULL
68  -30.66667 40.50000    68 FALSE     1 A21 A21.1  0  1768   26--26      0   NA   NULL
69  -30.50000 40.50000    69 FALSE     1 A21 A21.1  0  1768   26--26      0   NA   NULL
70  -30.50000 40.33333    70 FALSE     1 A21 A21.1  0  1768   26--26      0   NA   NULL
71  -30.33333 40.33333    71 FALSE     1 A22 A22.1  0  1769   26--27      0   NA   NULL
72  -30.50000 40.33333    72 FALSE     1 A22 A22.1  0  1769   26--27      0   NA   NULL
73  -30.50000 40.50000    73 FALSE     1 A22 A22.1  0  1769   26--27      0   NA   NULL
74  -30.33333 40.50000    74 FALSE     1 A22 A22.1  0  1769   26--27      0   NA   NULL
75  -30.33333 40.33333    75 FALSE     1 A22 A22.1  0  1769   26--27      0   NA   NULL
76  -30.16667 40.33333    76 FALSE     1 A23 A23.1  0  1770   26--28      4    1     OK
77  -30.33333 40.33333    77 FALSE     1 A23 A23.1  0  1770   26--28      4    1     OK
78  -30.33333 40.50000    78 FALSE     1 A23 A23.1  0  1770   26--28      4    1     OK
79  -30.16667 40.50000    79 FALSE     1 A23 A23.1  0  1770   26--28      4    1     OK
80  -30.16667 40.33333    80 FALSE     1 A23 A23.1  0  1770   26--28      4    1     OK
81  -30.00000 40.33333    81 FALSE     1 A24 A24.1  0  1771   26--29      0   NA   NULL
82  -30.16667 40.33333    82 FALSE     1 A24 A24.1  0  1771   26--29      0   NA   NULL
83  -30.16667 40.50000    83 FALSE     1 A24 A24.1  0  1771   26--29      0   NA   NULL
84  -30.00000 40.50000    84 FALSE     1 A24 A24.1  0  1771   26--29      0   NA   NULL
85  -30.00000 40.33333    85 FALSE     1 A24 A24.1  0  1771   26--29      0   NA   NULL
86  -29.83334 40.33333    86 FALSE     1 A25 A25.1  0  1772   26--30      4    2     OK
87  -30.00000 40.33333    87 FALSE     1 A25 A25.1  0  1772   26--30      4    2     OK
88  -30.00000 40.50000    88 FALSE     1 A25 A25.1  0  1772   26--30      4    2     OK
89  -29.83334 40.50000    89 FALSE     1 A25 A25.1  0  1772   26--30      4    2     OK
90  -29.83334 40.33333    90 FALSE     1 A25 A25.1  0  1772   26--30      4    2     OK
91  -29.66667 40.33333    91 FALSE     1 A26 A26.1  0  1773   26--31      4    7     OK
92  -29.83334 40.33333    92 FALSE     1 A26 A26.1  0  1773   26--31      4    7     OK
93  -29.83334 40.50000    93 FALSE     1 A26 A26.1  0  1773   26--31      4    7     OK
94  -29.66667 40.50000    94 FALSE     1 A26 A26.1  0  1773   26--31      4    7     OK
95  -29.66667 40.33333    95 FALSE     1 A26 A26.1  0  1773   26--31      4    7     OK
96  -29.50000 40.33333    96 FALSE     1 A27 A27.1  0  1774   26--32      4    1     OK
97  -29.66667 40.33333    97 FALSE     1 A27 A27.1  0  1774   26--32      4    1     OK
98  -29.66667 40.50000    98 FALSE     1 A27 A27.1  0  1774   26--32      4    1     OK
99  -29.50000 40.50000    99 FALSE     1 A27 A27.1  0  1774   26--32      4    1     OK
100 -29.50000 40.33333   100 FALSE     1 A27 A27.1  0  1774   26--32      4    1     OK
101 -29.33334 40.33333   101 FALSE     1 A28 A28.1  0  1775   26--33      4    1     OK
102 -29.50000 40.33333   102 FALSE     1 A28 A28.1  0  1775   26--33      4    1     OK
103 -29.50000 40.50000   103 FALSE     1 A28 A28.1  0  1775   26--33      4    1     OK
104 -29.33334 40.50000   104 FALSE     1 A28 A28.1  0  1775   26--33      4    1     OK
105 -29.33334 40.33333   105 FALSE     1 A28 A28.1  0  1775   26--33      4    1     OK
106 -29.16667 40.33333   106 FALSE     1 A29 A29.1  0  1776   26--34      0   NA   NULL
107 -29.33334 40.33333   107 FALSE     1 A29 A29.1  0  1776   26--34      0   NA   NULL
108 -29.33334 40.50000   108 FALSE     1 A29 A29.1  0  1776   26--34      0   NA   NULL
109 -29.16667 40.50000   109 FALSE     1 A29 A29.1  0  1776   26--34      0   NA   NULL
110 -29.16667 40.33333   110 FALSE     1 A29 A29.1  0  1776   26--34      0   NA   NULL
111 -33.50000 40.33333   111 FALSE     1  A3  A3.1  0  1750    26--8      0   NA   NULL
112 -33.66667 40.33333   112 FALSE     1  A3  A3.1  0  1750    26--8      0   NA   NULL
113 -33.66667 40.50000   113 FALSE     1  A3  A3.1  0  1750    26--8      0   NA   NULL
114 -33.50000 40.50000   114 FALSE     1  A3  A3.1  0  1750    26--8      0   NA   NULL
115 -33.50000 40.33333   115 FALSE     1  A3  A3.1  0  1750    26--8      0   NA   NULL
116 -29.00000 40.33333   116 FALSE     1 A30 A30.1  0  1777   26--35      0   NA   NULL
117 -29.16667 40.33333   117 FALSE     1 A30 A30.1  0  1777   26--35      0   NA   NULL
118 -29.16667 40.50000   118 FALSE     1 A30 A30.1  0  1777   26--35      0   NA   NULL
119 -29.00000 40.50000   119 FALSE     1 A30 A30.1  0  1777   26--35      0   NA   NULL
120 -29.00000 40.33333   120 FALSE     1 A30 A30.1  0  1777   26--35      0   NA   NULL
121 -28.83334 40.33333   121 FALSE     1 A31 A31.1  0  1778   26--36      0   NA   NULL
122 -29.00000 40.33333   122 FALSE     1 A31 A31.1  0  1778   26--36      0   NA   NULL
123 -29.00000 40.50000   123 FALSE     1 A31 A31.1  0  1778   26--36      0   NA   NULL
124 -28.83334 40.50000   124 FALSE     1 A31 A31.1  0  1778   26--36      0   NA   NULL
125 -28.83334 40.33333   125 FALSE     1 A31 A31.1  0  1778   26--36      0   NA   NULL
126 -28.66667 40.33333   126 FALSE     1 A32 A32.1  0  1779   26--37      0   NA   NULL
127 -28.83334 40.33333   127 FALSE     1 A32 A32.1  0  1779   26--37      0   NA   NULL
128 -28.83334 40.50000   128 FALSE     1 A32 A32.1  0  1779   26--37      0   NA   NULL
129 -28.66667 40.50000   129 FALSE     1 A32 A32.1  0  1779   26--37      0   NA   NULL
130 -28.66667 40.33333   130 FALSE     1 A32 A32.1  0  1779   26--37      0   NA   NULL
131 -28.50000 40.33333   131 FALSE     1 A33 A33.1  0  1780   26--38      0   NA   NULL
132 -28.66667 40.33333   132 FALSE     1 A33 A33.1  0  1780   26--38      0   NA   NULL
133 -28.66667 40.50000   133 FALSE     1 A33 A33.1  0  1780   26--38      0   NA   NULL
134 -28.50000 40.50000   134 FALSE     1 A33 A33.1  0  1780   26--38      0   NA   NULL
135 -28.50000 40.33333   135 FALSE     1 A33 A33.1  0  1780   26--38      0   NA   NULL
136 -28.33334 40.33333   136 FALSE     1 A34 A34.1  0  1781   26--39      0   NA   NULL
137 -28.50000 40.33333   137 FALSE     1 A34 A34.1  0  1781   26--39      0   NA   NULL
138 -28.50000 40.50000   138 FALSE     1 A34 A34.1  0  1781   26--39      0   NA   NULL
139 -28.33334 40.50000   139 FALSE     1 A34 A34.1  0  1781   26--39      0   NA   NULL
140 -28.33334 40.33333   140 FALSE     1 A34 A34.1  0  1781   26--39      0   NA   NULL
141 -28.16667 40.33333   141 FALSE     1 A35 A35.1  0  1782   26--40      0   NA   NULL
142 -28.33334 40.33333   142 FALSE     1 A35 A35.1  0  1782   26--40      0   NA   NULL
143 -28.33334 40.50000   143 FALSE     1 A35 A35.1  0  1782   26--40      0   NA   NULL
144 -28.16667 40.50000   144 FALSE     1 A35 A35.1  0  1782   26--40      0   NA   NULL
145 -28.16667 40.33333   145 FALSE     1 A35 A35.1  0  1782   26--40      0   NA   NULL
146 -28.00000 40.33333   146 FALSE     1 A36 A36.1  0  1783   26--41      4    1     OK
147 -28.16667 40.33333   147 FALSE     1 A36 A36.1  0  1783   26--41      4    1     OK
148 -28.16667 40.50000   148 FALSE     1 A36 A36.1  0  1783   26--41      4    1     OK
149 -28.00000 40.50000   149 FALSE     1 A36 A36.1  0  1783   26--41      4    1     OK
150 -28.00000 40.33333   150 FALSE     1 A36 A36.1  0  1783   26--41      4    1     OK
151 -27.83334 40.33333   151 FALSE     1 A37 A37.1  0  1784   26--42      0   NA   NULL
152 -28.00000 40.33333   152 FALSE     1 A37 A37.1  0  1784   26--42      0   NA   NULL
153 -28.00000 40.50000   153 FALSE     1 A37 A37.1  0  1784   26--42      0   NA   NULL
154 -27.83334 40.50000   154 FALSE     1 A37 A37.1  0  1784   26--42      0   NA   NULL
155 -27.83334 40.33333   155 FALSE     1 A37 A37.1  0  1784   26--42      0   NA   NULL
156 -27.66667 40.33333   156 FALSE     1 A38 A38.1  0  1785   26--43      0   NA   NULL
157 -27.83334 40.33333   157 FALSE     1 A38 A38.1  0  1785   26--43      0   NA   NULL
158 -27.83334 40.50000   158 FALSE     1 A38 A38.1  0  1785   26--43      0   NA   NULL
159 -27.66667 40.50000   159 FALSE     1 A38 A38.1  0  1785   26--43      0   NA   NULL
160 -27.66667 40.33333   160 FALSE     1 A38 A38.1  0  1785   26--43      0   NA   NULL
161 -27.50000 40.33333   161 FALSE     1 A39 A39.1  0  1786   26--44      2   NA     OK
162 -27.66667 40.33333   162 FALSE     1 A39 A39.1  0  1786   26--44      2   NA     OK
163 -27.66667 40.50000   163 FALSE     1 A39 A39.1  0  1786   26--44      2   NA     OK
164 -27.50000 40.50000   164 FALSE     1 A39 A39.1  0  1786   26--44      2   NA     OK
165 -27.50000 40.33333   165 FALSE     1 A39 A39.1  0  1786   26--44      2   NA     OK
166 -33.33333 40.33333   166 FALSE     1  A4  A4.1  0  1751    26--9      0   NA   NULL
167 -33.50000 40.33333   167 FALSE     1  A4  A4.1  0  1751    26--9      0   NA   NULL
168 -33.50000 40.50000   168 FALSE     1  A4  A4.1  0  1751    26--9      0   NA   NULL
169 -33.33333 40.50000   169 FALSE     1  A4  A4.1  0  1751    26--9      0   NA   NULL
170 -33.33333 40.33333   170 FALSE     1  A4  A4.1  0  1751    26--9      0   NA   NULL
171 -27.33334 40.33333   171 FALSE     1 A40 A40.1  0  1787   26--45      0   NA   NULL
172 -27.50000 40.33333   172 FALSE     1 A40 A40.1  0  1787   26--45      0   NA   NULL
173 -27.50000 40.50000   173 FALSE     1 A40 A40.1  0  1787   26--45      0   NA   NULL
174 -27.33334 40.50000   174 FALSE     1 A40 A40.1  0  1787   26--45      0   NA   NULL
175 -27.33334 40.33333   175 FALSE     1 A40 A40.1  0  1787   26--45      0   NA   NULL
176 -27.16667 40.33333   176 FALSE     1 A41 A41.1  0  1788   26--46      0   NA   NULL
177 -27.33334 40.33333   177 FALSE     1 A41 A41.1  0  1788   26--46      0   NA   NULL
178 -27.33334 40.50000   178 FALSE     1 A41 A41.1  0  1788   26--46      0   NA   NULL
179 -27.16667 40.50000   179 FALSE     1 A41 A41.1  0  1788   26--46      0   NA   NULL
180 -27.16667 40.33333   180 FALSE     1 A41 A41.1  0  1788   26--46      0   NA   NULL
181 -27.00000 40.33333   181 FALSE     1 A42 A42.1  0  1789   26--47      0   NA   NULL
182 -27.16667 40.33333   182 FALSE     1 A42 A42.1  0  1789   26--47      0   NA   NULL
183 -27.16667 40.50000   183 FALSE     1 A42 A42.1  0  1789   26--47      0   NA   NULL
184 -27.00000 40.50000   184 FALSE     1 A42 A42.1  0  1789   26--47      0   NA   NULL
185 -27.00000 40.33333   185 FALSE     1 A42 A42.1  0  1789   26--47      0   NA   NULL
186 -26.83334 40.33333   186 FALSE     1 A43 A43.1  0  1790   26--48      2   NA     OK
187 -27.00000 40.33333   187 FALSE     1 A43 A43.1  0  1790   26--48      2   NA     OK
188 -27.00000 40.50000   188 FALSE     1 A43 A43.1  0  1790   26--48      2   NA     OK
189 -26.83334 40.50000   189 FALSE     1 A43 A43.1  0  1790   26--48      2   NA     OK
190 -26.83334 40.33333   190 FALSE     1 A43 A43.1  0  1790   26--48      2   NA     OK
191 -26.66667 40.33333   191 FALSE     1 A44 A44.1  0  1791   26--49      0   NA   NULL
192 -26.83334 40.33333   192 FALSE     1 A44 A44.1  0  1791   26--49      0   NA   NULL
193 -26.83334 40.50000   193 FALSE     1 A44 A44.1  0  1791   26--49      0   NA   NULL
194 -26.66667 40.50000   194 FALSE     1 A44 A44.1  0  1791   26--49      0   NA   NULL
195 -26.66667 40.33333   195 FALSE     1 A44 A44.1  0  1791   26--49      0   NA   NULL
196 -26.50000 40.33333   196 FALSE     1 A45 A45.1  0  1792   26--50      0   NA   NULL
197 -26.66667 40.33333   197 FALSE     1 A45 A45.1  0  1792   26--50      0   NA   NULL
198 -26.66667 40.50000   198 FALSE     1 A45 A45.1  0  1792   26--50      0   NA   NULL
199 -26.50000 40.50000   199 FALSE     1 A45 A45.1  0  1792   26--50      0   NA   NULL
200 -26.50000 40.33333   200 FALSE     1 A45 A45.1  0  1792   26--50      0   NA   NULL
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(DF)` in your question? You'll be more likely to get help that way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added a part of the data base (the matrix is too hudge to have something correct with the function `dput()`)